# Use dynamic variable value to check if corresponding value exists in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a list of buttons in a menu that all have a unique ID and a collapse-able menu underneath it. When I click one of these buttons I want to use the ID of the clicked button to check if there is a key with the same ID already stored in the local storage.

If there IS already a key in local storage with the same clicked button ID, then I want to update the value of the key to true/false (depending on the collapse-able menu).

If there IS NOT already a key in local storage with the same clicked button ID, then I want to add a new key and value to the local storage using the ID of the clicked button.

I haven't been able to figure out how to use the ID of the clicked button to check if it exists in local storage. I have been able to write a single new key, but it just replaces the existing key/value, so it's only replacing a single pair instead of adding new pairs to the object/array.

I have searched for several hours already today and I just haven't been able to figure out why this won't work.

**MORE INFO:**
I wanted to add a little reasoning to why I am doing this. I have over 30 different collapse-able panels in a side navigation menu. I want the browser to remember which panels the user has open/closed, but I didn't want to write and if/else statement for every single one. And there will be panels that are added or removed in the future, so I didn't want to have to update this local storage code in the future. I just want everything to happen automatically in the local storage. So, I am just looking for a way to dynamically write these panel IDs and states to the local storage, and then loop through all of them in a mutation observer on page load to open/close them automatically.

Here is my HTML code that has specific classes and IDs:

```
<a href="#" class="rpLink rpExpandable rpExpanded" id="button-id-one">Menu Button One</a>
<a href="#" class="rpLink rpExpandable" id="button-id-two">Menu Button Two</a>
<a href="#" class="rpLink rpExpandable" id="button-id-three">Menu Button Three</a>
```

Here is my JS code that listens for when the menu buttons are clicked:

```
$(document).on("click",".rpExpandable",function()
{
    var panelId = $(this).attr("id");
    var panelState = false;

    if($(this).hasClass("rpExpanded")){panelState = true;}

    //update left menu panel settings in local storage
    persistLeftMenuPreferences(panelId,panelState);
});
```

Here is my JS code that tries to check the local storage and add to it or update it:

```
function persistLeftMenuPreferences(panelId,panelState)
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        var panelKey = "panel-preferences";
        var panelPreferences = {};

        if(localStorage.getItem(panelId) !== null)
        {
            console.log("not null");
            panelPreferences.panels[panelId] = panelState;
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("null");
            panelPreferences.panels = [panelId,panelState];
        }

        //set item values in local storage
        localStorage.setItem(panelKey, JSON.stringify(panelPreferences));
        Cookies.set(panelKey, JSON.stringify(panelPreferences), {expires: 360});
    }, 200);
}
```

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

So, I have found that the code below is actually doing what I want for the most part. The only down-side is that it's adding individual key/value pairs instead of putting them all in to one object that contains all of the key/value pairs inside of it. If you can show me how to put them all inside of a single object, that would be ideal.

```
function persistLeftMenuPreferences(panelId,panelState)
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        var panelPreferences = {};

        panelPreferences = [panelId,panelState];

        //set item values in local storage
        localStorage.setItem(panelId, JSON.stringify(panelPreferences));
        Cookies.set(panelId, JSON.stringify(panelPreferences), {expires: 360});
    }, 200);
}
```

**LATEST EDIT/UPDATE:**

I've simplified my code even more. I am just writing the panelId and panelState directly to the local storage instead of trying to put it in an object. Ultimately I'd like each key/value pair to be inserted in to a single object, but I will save it for a later day.

```
function persistLeftMenuPreferences(panelId,panelState)
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        //set item values in local storage
        localStorage.setItem(panelId, panelState);
        Cookies.set(panelId, panelState, {expires: 360});
    }, 200);
}
```

Here is a screenshot of how this looks when adding them to the local storage:
[screenshot of local storage key/value paris](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnxUz.png)

Comment: Why are you using `setTimeout()`?

Comment: The setTimeout() is being used to allow the changes to finish up in the DOM before updating the local storage values. Maybe not needed for this particular function, but I am updating other local storage data and the setTimeout() just makes sure my other manipulations on the page are finished up and I get all the correct values. Without it I wasn't getting the updated values.

Comment: Why move away from the (singular) JSON object in favour of the (multiple) name/value pairs?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius - I would ultimately love to have it work that way, but I can't figure out how to make that work the way I want, thus the reason I created this question. I am not so great at JavaScript, and I certainly haven't totally grasped the JSON concept, so I struggled getting something to work. I've already spent a lot of time getting it to work the way it is, so I am happy with what I have at the moment. But I would certainly love to have it in a single JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the old value of `panelPreferences` from local storage and update that, not start with an empty object.

You shouldn't be using `panelId` as the local storage key. It's the key in the JSON object that's saved in local storage, with the key `panel-preferences`.

```js
function persistLeftMenuPreferences(panelId, panelState) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var panelKey = "panel-preferences";
    var panelPreferences

    if (localStorage.getItem(panelKey) !== null) {
      console.log("not null");
      panelPreferences = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(panelId));
    } else {
      console.log("null");
      panelPreferences.panels = {};
    }
    panelPreferences[panelId] = panelState;
    //set item values in local storage
    localStorage.setItem(panelKey, JSON.stringify(panelPreferences));
    Cookies.set(panelKey, JSON.stringify(panelPreferences), {
      expires: 360
    });
  }, 200);
}
```

Comment: I understand that the 'IF' part of this function now runs per your code, but it's still not checking for the specific ID of the clicked button in the local storage. It's just generally checking if the 'panel-key' object exists, and then totally replaces it. I want to know how to check if a specific key/value pair exists inside of the 'panel-key' object. If it does, I just want to update the value of that particular key. But then if they don't, then add a new key/value pair to the panelKey object. I will update my original question with some more details.

Comment: It doesn't totally replace it. It reads the old value, merges the current key into it, and saves that updated value.

Comment: Yeah, I see it doing that. However, I have ended up simplifying this whole idea even more, after several hours of trial and error. I added my updated code in my original question. I'd still love to be able to get all of these individual key/value pairs in to a single object in the local storage and be able to push new pairs in to the original object while being able to modify existing pairs.

Comment: If you have a solution you should post it as an answer, not in the question.

Comment: I am still working on the ultimate answer to this question, which is to have every key/value pair in one object. When I get that to work I will update this question with an answer that completely works.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the comment of yesterday regarding JSON vs multiple name/value pairs perhaps this might be of interest. I wrote a simple class a while back for working with storage objects which makes the setting and toggling (true/false) of a key/value pair remarkably simple in this instance. By default it will be creating and working with JSON which is ideal for your use case. I can't see why the need to use both `localStorage` and a `cookie` - no jQuery code as I never use it but sure it'll be an easy transposition...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style> 
            /* just a little basic css to prettify it */
            body{ 
                width:100%;
                height:100vh;
                margin:0;
                display:flex;
                flex-direction:column;
                justify-content:flex-start;
                align-content: stretch;
            }
            body *{
                transition:linear all 250ms
            }
            .rpLink{ 
                margin:0.5rem;
                padding:1rem;
                border:2px solid grey;
                border-radius:0.5rem;
                background:white;
                align-self:auto;
                width:150px;
                text-align:center;
                text-decoration:none;
            }
            .rpLink:hover{
                background:rgba(0,200,0,0.25)
            }
            
            .rpExpLogged{
                /* 
                helper css class. 
                Open the panel, make it sing and dance or whatever
                */
                border:2px solid black;
                background:rgba(0,200,0,0.75);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <!-- example NAV menu taking some of observed panel names/ids -->
        <a href="#" class="rpLink rpExpandable rpExpanded" id="sis-carrier-info-panel">SIS Carrier Info</a>
        <a href="#" class="rpLink rpExpandable" id="sis-app-mover-panel">SIS App mover</a>
        <a href="#" class="rpLink rpExpandable" id="sis-student-survey-panel">SIS Student survey</a>
        <a href="#" class="rpLink rpExpandable" id="sis-reports-panel">SIS Reports</a>
        <a href="#" class="rpLink rpExpandable" id="sis-loan-mods-panel">SIS Loan Mods</a>
        <a href="#" class="rpLink rpExpandable" id="sis-finance-panel">SIS Finance</a>
        
        
        
        <script>
        
            /*************************************************
                basic class to further simplify working with
                storage objects. By default localStorage is
                used, easily overridden.
            */
            class StoreFactory{
                constructor( name, local=true ){
                    this.name=name;
                    this.engine=local==true ? localStorage : sessionStorage;
                    return this;
                };
                set( data ){
                    if( data )this.engine.setItem( this.name, JSON.stringify( data ) );
                };
                get(){
                    return this.exists( name ) ? JSON.parse( this.engine.getItem( this.name ) ) : false;
                };
                exists(){
                    return this.engine.getItem( this.name )==null ? false : true;
                };
                create(){
                    if( !this.exists() ) this.set( arguments[0] || {} );
                    return this;
                };
                getkey( key ){
                    return this.get().hasOwnProperty( key ) ? this.get()[ key ] : false;
                };
                setkey( key, value ){
                    let data=this.get();
                        data[ key ]=value;
                    this.set( data );
                };
                save(){
                    this.set( this.get() );
                }
            };
            
            
            
            
            /***********************************
                The name of the storage object
                & helper css classnames.
            */
            const config={
                store:'panel_preferences',
                css_logged:'rpExpLogged',
                css_panel:'rpExpandable'
            };
            
            
            /***********************************************************************
                create the instance of the Storage Object - create default 
                type if it does not exist by calling `create` method.
                If the store already exists nothing happens when calling `create()`
            */
            let oStore=new StoreFactory( config.store );
                oStore.create();
            
            
            /*******************************
                single delegated listener
            */
            document.addEventListener('click',e=>{
                if( e.target.classList.contains( config.css_panel ) && e.target instanceof HTMLAnchorElement ){
                    /************************************************************************
                        check for the key ( using event to identify object & get its ID ) 
                        & then set initial value of true. This will toggle on subsequent 
                        clicks by using !value type syntax
                    */
                    let data=oStore.getkey( e.target.id );
                    oStore.setkey( e.target.id, !data );
                    
                    /******************************************************************
                        The above could, if desired, be rewritten as a one-liner
                        -> oStore.setkey( e.target.id, !oStore.getkey( e.target.id ) )
                    */
                    
                    
                    
                    /****************************************************
                        Set some sort of identifying class / attribute. 
                        -> OPEN/CLOSE a panel etc
                    */
                    e.target.classList.toggle( config.css_logged );
                }
            });
            
            
            
            /**************************************************
                At page load - restore the panel states by
                adding class to each item found in storage.
            */
            document.querySelectorAll( `.${config.css_panel}` ).forEach(n=>{
                if( oStore.getkey( n.id ) )n.classList.add( config.css_logged )
            });
            
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```